# How do I solve these cookies related warnings in nuxt?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

What are these errors I'm getting in my browser? And how do I fix it?
I am usgin nuxt with typescript and using `cookie-universal-nuxt` to store auth token.

```
Cookie “exp_last_visit” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/4.js” because the scheme does not match. 4.js
Cookie “exp_last_activity” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/4.js” because the scheme does not match. 4.js
Cookie “exp_csrf_token” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/4.js” because the scheme does not match. 4.js
Cookie “__stripe_sid” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/4.js” because the scheme does not match. 4.js
Cookie “__stripe_mid” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/4.js” because the scheme does not match. 4.js
Cookie “XSRF-TOKEN” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/4.js” because the scheme does not match. 4.js
Cookie “laravel_session” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/4.js” because the scheme does not match. 4.js
Cookie “exp_last_visit” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/3.js” because the scheme does not match. 3.js
Cookie “exp_last_activity” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/3.js” because the scheme does not match. 3.js
Cookie “exp_csrf_token” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/3.js” because the scheme does not match. 3.js
Cookie “__stripe_sid” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/3.js” because the scheme does not match. 3.js
Cookie “__stripe_mid” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/3.js” because the scheme does not match. 3.js
Cookie “XSRF-TOKEN” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/3.js” because the scheme does not match. 3.js
Cookie “laravel_session” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://ts-nuxt.pv/_nuxt/3.js” because the scheme does not match.
```